# Info about this older transformer from my Kimball organ

Tags: transformer, synthesizer

I have been harvesting parts from my dying kimball "Swinger 300" and I finally got around to disassembling the power supply. It had what I assumed to be a transformer attached, as the only labelling on it is "210-031-00  30-7604  CIN-TRAN 1093". It has three red wires on one side and 2 black wires and a blue wire of thinner gauge on the opposite side. The core seems to be a bunch of metal shims pressed together, and the coils are wrapped up in what seems to be rather cheap tape and crepe paper. Is there a good way of looking into older electrical components like this? and does anyone have any information on reverse engineering older types of transformers like this? I have been wanting to try an electromagnet conversion using a transformer, but all this crepe paper makes disassembly a lot more messy and less direct.

Comment: There may be special-interest groups interested in discussing restoration like this. If there are no such groups, or you cannot find any and must work alone on it -- unable to find specifications per the labeling, then it's a sit-down project of analyzing what you have in front of you. Probably by carefully making measurements and unwrapping its wiring carefully noting diameters and numbers of loops, where and how placed, etc. A set of good photographs may help get some advice or thoughts before digging into something like that.